# Simplest Golang CGI form example

Tags: go, cgi

I'd appreciate some help with the most basic possible CGI program with a form input.  I don't want to run a listener or use a framework or do anything beyond the most basic possible example.  This is just to get my feet in the door, and I will add the bells and whistles later.

Here's a simple CGI app without a form input:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
        ip := os.Getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")
        fmt.Printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n")
        fmt.Println(ip)
}
```

This prints my IP address when I go to https://example.com/cgi-bin/ip

However, the following code results in a 502 error:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        s "strings"
)

func main() {
        var r *http.Request

        fmt.Printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
        fmt.Println("<!DOCTYPE html>")
        fmt.Println("<title>login</title>")
        r.ParseForm()
        username := r.FormValue("username")
        password := r.FormValue("password")
        if s.Compare(password, username) == 0 {
                fmt.Println("<p>invalid username/password")
        }
}
```

The nginx log says:

2017/04/29 22:55:12 [error] 45768#0: *802 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.0.2.80, server: example.com, request: "POST /cgi-bin/login HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:run/slowcgi.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/login.html"

The HTML for this form is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Username and password</title>

<form action="/cgi-bin/login" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td> </td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Another note: this is nginx on OpenBSD, using slowcgi(8).  Since my toy "ip" program works, I believe my Go code is the problem.

What am I doing wrong in my Go code?  Thank you!

EDIT: I now have the following code, which doesn't compile. What am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "net/http/cgi"
)

func main() {
        httpReq, err := cgi.Request()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, err.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        r := httpReq.ParseForm()
        username := r.FormValue("username")
        password := r.FormValue("password")

        fmt.Printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
        fmt.Printf("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
        fmt.Printf("<p>username: %s\n", username)
        fmt.Printf("<p>password: %s\n", password)
}
```

Comment: Your request `r` is `nil`, calling `ParseForm` on it will result in a panic. Go will not magically allocate that request for you, instead try using the [net/http/cgi](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cgi/) package and calling the `cgi.Request()` function to retrieve the request you want to call `ParseForm` on.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please see my edit above, where I try using cgi.Request() as suggested.

Comment: Please include the error from the compiler @jdaws.

Comment: `ParseForm` returns a value of type `error`, so in your edited code `r` is of type `error` which has no `FormValue`, that's why it won't compile. Instead try something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/-oQ2P6VMEn

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva, I copy/pasted that code snippet, which compiles, but I still get a 502 error in nginx with the same error log as in my original post. This is Go 1.8. My little "ip" program above works, so I know CGI is working in nginx, and I also did a test C program which correctly showed my POST data.

Comment: Does the Go app output anything to Stderr?

Comment: No, it doesn't output anything to Stderr.

Answer (score 4):

Since [net/http/cgi](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cgi/) is not working for you and looking at the error log from nginx mentioning FastCGI, you might need to use the [net/http/fcgi](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/) package.

If you look at its documentation you can see that you'll need to do a little bit more work to get access to the request.

First declare a function that will be used to handle the requests:

```
func myhandler(_ http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // handle request
}
```

Then pass your new handler to the [fcgi.Serve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/#Serve) function.

```
fcgi.Serve(nil, http.HandlerFunc(myhandler))
```

`Serve` takes two parameters. The first one is a `net.Listener`, if passed in as `nil`, `Serve` will read the requests from `stdin`. The second one, is of type [http.Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) which is an interface that the `myhandler` function, as is, does not implement but given its specific signature (`func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)`) you can convert `myhandler` to an `http.Handler` using the [http.HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) type.

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http/fcgi"
    "os"
)

func myhandler(_ http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    username := r.FormValue("username")
    password := r.FormValue("password")

    fmt.Printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
    fmt.Printf("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
    fmt.Printf("<p>username: %s\n", username)
    fmt.Printf("<p>password: %s\n", password)
}

func main() {
    if err := fcgi.Serve(nil, http.HandlerFunc(myhandler)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand well You are saying that the fcgi server will gracefully degrade to CGI mode.
I compiled your code after adding "net/http" to the import section, but the script panics with the following error:

  panic: file file+net /dev/stdin: getsockopt: socket operation on non-socket
I would like to make a Go program which gracefully degrades to CGI mode if FASTCGI mode is not present.

Comment: Is this the same thing like yours what BEEGO is doing here?
https://github.com/beego/beego/blob/f6b75434781631db394461d9f4778838e4abf58e/server/web/server.go#L104
Thanks!

Comment: @Беров AFAICT fcgi will *not* gracefully degrade to cgi by itself, also I don't think I made that claim in the answer. However you should be able to degrade gracefully yourself if you want to by checking the error from `fcgi.Serve` and, instead of panicking when the error is non-nil, handling the request with cgi.

Comment: No, most definitely FCGI will _not_ degrade gracefully to CGI. What you need is to set up your `nginx` configuration to use something like what is described [here](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi/wiki/Systemd) — assuming that your FreeBSD box uses `systemd`, this will be rather easy to set up properly.